# Convertir una fecha definida como String a un nuevo formato en Java

Tags: java

Quiero convertir una fecha que recibo como parámetro de la siguiente manera:

```
String fecha = "aaaammdd"; //----- Recibido como parámetro.
```

convertirlo a "yymmdd". Lo hice con `SimpleDateFormat` pero no me funciona, me dice que la conversión no es correcta.

Adjunto el código de cómo lo estoy haciendo en Java

```
public String findFile(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yymmdd");
    String fecha = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println("Formato de fecha: " fecha);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo.. como parametro recibis el formato.. el formato que vos queres de salida?

Comment: no se entiende bien el formato de entrada y salida, decis aaaammdd que es la a??

Answer (score 3):

Si estás recibiendo una fecha como `20230328` y quieres transformarla a `230328`, puedes simplemente quitar los dos primeros caracteres:

```
String anyoDosDigitos = fecha.substring(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Para convertir la cadena a nuevo formato, osea a un objeto "fecha, puedes usar la clase Localdate:

Indicamos el formato.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMdd" );
```

Creamos la fecha.

```
String dia = "19801231";
Localdate fecha = Localdate.parse( dia, dateformatter );
```

Mostramos.

```
dateformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
System.out.println( dateformatter.format( fecha ));
```